# How to install Veyon on RPi 4

Tags: apt, raspbian-buster

I want to install [Veyon](https://veyon.io/) on the RPi4. I have read about [Debian packages](https://launchpad.net/~veyon/+archive/ubuntu/stable) and the instructions.

I had a look in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` and it had an entry for `buster`, so I added the line for Veyon Buster:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/veyon/stable/ubuntu bionic main
```

I then tried to run the command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:veyon/stable
```

but there is no `add-apt-repository` on my Raspberry and I could not install that with `sudo apt install`.

Using only

```
sudo apt-get update
```

does not work, because there are keys missing, so the source is not trusted. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but here's the answer to your question:

It seems you may be looking in the wrong place. If you want to learn if a package is available on your RPi, try this:

```
apt-cache search xxxx
```

In your case, 'xxxx' is `veyon`, and so on my Pi w/ buster:

```
$ apt-cache search veyon
libveyon-core - Computer Monitoring and Classroom Management Software - libraries
veyon-configurator - Computer Monitoring and Classroom Management Software - configurator
veyon-master - Computer Monitoring and Classroom Management Software - master
veyon-plugins - Computer Monitoring and Classroom Management Software - plugins
veyon-service - Computer Monitoring and Classroom Management Software - client service
```

Best practice for installation of a new package is as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot              # to be sure any kernel or firmware upgrades are running
sudo apt-get install veyon-xxx  # whichever ones you need
```

Comment: Darn! So that change in `/etc/apt/sources.list` would not even have been required, because Veyon is already in the default RPi repositories?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Not only is it not required, it will (probably) break your system if you don't remove it. Remember: RPi uses a RISC/ARM processor, and code compiled for Intel/AMD processors is incompatible.